# What is the purpose of background.js on a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't see use for background.js or background.html just yet. It seems like just a middle man. I can easily communicate with all my content scripts by using the following code in popup.html/popup.js (browser action):

```
if (e.target.id === "blue"){
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
     var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "blue" });
});
}
```

then on my content.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

 if( request.message === "blue" ) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
     console.log("Content: Changing to blue");
 }

 if( request.message === "black" ) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
}

 });
```

P.S Hope this helps someone out, I already have a working extension ! :D

Comment: I ran into this the other day.. I think maybe it could have special permissions for persisting data or something? I would like to know.

Comment: @JaromandaX I wanted to know what the purpose of background.js is ? It seems like just a middle man.

Comment: @gegillam I think it's for managing scripts I don't know. I was able to do fine with just communicating with browser action and content scripts didn't really see a need for background.js.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes , many times. I usually read alot before asking questions on here.

Comment: @JaromandaX you're suppose to be helpful not criticize those who are trying to learn. Please don't bother responding.

Answer (score 1):

a file named `background.js` has no significance in chrome extensions, you must be asking about [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)

These pages do not have to have any particular name, they can be called `fred.js` or `wilma.js` - their "special purpose" is only realised if one adds them to the extension through the chrome extension manifest like so:

```
// background page
"background": {
  "scripts": ["fred.js"]
},
// event page
"background": {
  "scripts": ["wilma.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
```

The functionality offered by and use case for such pages is in the above linked documentation pages

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

Extensions are event based programs used to modify or enhance the Chrome browsing experience. Events are browser triggers, such as navigating to a new page, removing a bookmark, or closing a tab. Extensions monitor these events in their **background script**, then react with specified instructions.